# Using jcenter and mavenCentral both in Android Studio

Tags: maven, android-studio, jcenter

I am new to Android Studio. I am using libraries in my project. The maven central has updated version of facebook sdk, while rest of libraries I am using are available on jcenter. I want to know if we can use both these repositories in  our project. If yes, then how do I need it to define in gradle file so that studio downloads aar from correct location. Any example would be helpful.

Answer (score 46):

and for maven just add to your pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jcenter</id>
      <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 24):

You never need both. JCenter is a superset of Maven Central, and it should suffice for all the dependencies.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: is this tested and verified? if the repo in its readme specified adding mavencentral and i just add jcenter it will get it and always get the right one?

Comment: Yes it will. It's the default in Android Studio generated scripts (when you start a new project, for example), and it works great for everybody.

Comment: btw, an off-topic comment. Can you point me to a good tutorial to get started with BinTray? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: @AndroidMechanic this one is good - https://medium.com/@ryanseys/publishing-to-maven-central-and-jcenter-2b6376424856#.ra7c3r8mc

Comment: //You never need both// - not always true; I found this [ojdbc.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14/10.2.0.4.0) in maven repo but not in jcenter.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use both repositories even though you don't need both unless you want to work offline.

Go to your build.gradle file in your app folder and type the following code:

```
buildscript 
{
repositories 
{
    jcenter{ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
dependencies 
{
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}
}

allprojects 
{
repositories 
{
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Comment: doesn't there need to be a call to maven() in the repositories section?