# Why can jcenter not resolve a dependency while mavenCentral can?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, maven-central, jcenter

I have a project with just two dependencies, the relatively standard `appcompat-v7` and [`ion`](https://github.com/koush/ion). So my gradle files are pretty straightforward:

**Project**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**App**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "zz.yy.xx"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6'
}
```

In fact I think the only thing I added myself is the `ion` dependency.

I'm not a gradle guru, but I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852219/android-buildscript-repositories-jcenter-vs-mavencentral) in [multiple places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137263/what-is-included-in-jcenter-repository-in-gradle) that [jcenter is a so called superset of mavenCentral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961025/using-jcenter-and-mavencentral-both-in-android-studio). Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28416430/1843331)

> JCenter itself is a thin veneer on top of Maven Central. **It proxies it** (more or less successfully) **and adds additional components.** Both are hosted on CDN networks and highly performant. Maven Central itself is the target for all Eclipse, Apache and most other open source projects and without it JCenter would be mostly empty.

and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32000765/1843331)

> You never need both. JCenter is a superset of Maven Central, and it should be suffice for all the dependencies.
>
> <sub>I am with JFrog, the company behind Bintray and [artifactory], see my profile for details and links.</sub>

make me believe that they are essentially the same as far as providing software packages goes, only jcenter is better in some way. Especially the poster of the latter answer appears to know what he is talking about.

However, I *cannot* pull in the ion dependency with jcenter. I always get this error

[image]

To get it to work, I need to add mavenCentral as well. So the above gradle snippet doesn't work, but if I change `allprojects` to this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

it magically starts working.

How is this possible? I have verified that both offer the package:

- http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.koushikdutta.ion%7Cion%7C2.1.6%7Cjar
- https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.koushikdutta.ion%3Aion/2.1.6/view

Gradle settings

[image]

I've tried the local wrapper with no success.

Android Studio 1.3.2
Gradle 1.3.0

Comment: does the build itself fails after you do a sync?

Comment: @user2511882 It's actually the sync that fails - see edit

Comment: Yes, thats what i was asking for.. anyways, i am able to get that "ion" dependency in...however, it works only if i switch the classpath to 1.1.0.. fails here as well for 1.3.0, which is rather interesting.

Comment: The file is for sure downloadable from JCenter - https://bintray.com/artifact/download/bintray/jcenter/com/koushikdutta/ion/ion/2.1.6/ion-2.1.6.jar, so Gradle should be able to fetch it. 

Can it be possible that Bintray is blocked by your proxy or firewall?

Comment: @JBaruch how would I check that? I have no websites blocked in my router settings, I don't use a proxy and I can access the bintray site and ion just fine in the browser

Comment: That's weird... I tried to fetch it from an Android project and the Gradle sync worked all right. And I am using the 1.3.0 plugin version

Comment: Can you please try and add `:jar` in the end of the dependency declaration?

Comment: @JBaruch Tried `compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6:jar'`, got the same error

Comment: Could you try compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6@jar'?

Comment: @ptitvinou same error still

Comment: @JBaruch I am thinking it is network related, because at my girlfrields house it works. I will do some testing when I get home tomorrow

Comment: I was going to do tests, but forgot about it because I wasn't prompted by the error. Somehow it solved itself. Perhaps temporary connectivity issues..?