# TestNG: Skip iteration based on logic

Tags: java, testng

I have seen many answers on how to skip the **whole @Test**, but I am trying to skip a specific *iteration* without having to adding extra metadata to dozens of existing tests:

```
public class TestNgPlayground {

        public static final DayOfWeek SOME_CONST = DayOfWeek.TUESDAY;

        @DataProvider
        public Object[][] getStuff(){
            return new Object[][] {
                    { "param1", DayOfWeek.MONDAY},    // Skip this
                    { "param2", DayOfWeek.TUESDAY },  // Run this
                    { "param3", DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY } // Skip this
            };
        }

        // Ideally I want to detect and Skip in @BeforeMethod / @BeforeClass

        @BeforeMethod  // testArgs fetches the DataProvider values
        public void setUp(Object[] testArgs,ITestResult result ){ 

            DayOfWeek dataProviderValue = (DayOfWeek) testArgs[1];

            if(dataProviderValue!= SOME_CONST ) {
    //            throw new SkipException("skip test"); // No good - skips the entire Test
    //            result.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);   // Doesn't do anything
            }
        }


        @Test(dataProvider = "getStuff")
        public void testt(String param1, DayOfWeek param2){
            // some testing
        }

        // 2nd best option - overwrite to Skip after test has run, 
        // though time has been wasted
        @AfterMethod
        public void tearDown(ITestResult result){

            DayOfWeek dow = (DayOfWeek) result.getParameters()[1];

            if(dow != SOME_CONST){
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP); // Doesn't do anything either... ?
            }


        }
    }
```

For the above example, I want the final report to show:

Iteration 1 - Skipped

Iteration 2 - Passed

Iteration 3 - Skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very easily by leveraging the IHookable interface that TestNG provides. Now within the `run()` method, you would get the ability to decide as to what you want to do with a particular iteration and even alter the status accordingly.

Here's a sample that shows how to do this.

```java
import org.testng.IHookCallBack;
import org.testng.IHookable;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;

public class TestNgPlayground implements IHookable {

    private static final DayOfWeek SOME_CONST = DayOfWeek.TUESDAY;

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getStuff() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {"param1", DayOfWeek.MONDAY},    // Skip this
                {"param2", DayOfWeek.TUESDAY},  // Run this
                {"param3", DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY} // Skip this
        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "getStuff")
    public void testt(String param1, DayOfWeek param2) {
        System.err.println("[" + param1 + ", " + param2 + "]");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {
        Object[] parameters = callBack.getParameters();
        DayOfWeek dataProviderValue = (DayOfWeek) parameters[1];
        if (dataProviderValue != SOME_CONST) {
            callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
        } else {
            testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
[param1, MONDAY]
[param3, WEDNESDAY]

Test ignored.

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

Comment: I've literally copy pasted your entire example into my Intellij, even ran in debug mode to ensure `testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);` is hit, yet the output is still that all 3 tests are run (no skips). Any idea what the discrepancy might be?

Comment: What version of TestNG are you using. Can you please try with 6.12 ( as of today this is the latest released version )

Comment: Magic! Was on 6.9; Moved to 6.11 and it works. Thank you. Where do you see 6.12, given that -> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng shows 6.11 only?

Comment: TestNG 6.12 hasn't made it to Maven central yet. It's available in JCenter though. You merely need to add a repository entry to your pom file to also refer to JCenter. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39164063) for more details.

Comment: Need to actually throw a SkipException for it to be seen as skipped